# Which characters are invalid in salt for SHA512?

Tags: salt, sha512, dovecot

Could you write which characters are invalid for SHA512 crypt in salt? I generate hashes in php and then use them for dovecot. I know colon : is causing problems, but which other chars are forbidden (from 32-127 range)?

Answer (score 1):

For the Unix `mkpasswd` implementations, only `[a-zA-Z0-9/.]` are allowed:

https://github.com/maximeh/buildroot/blob/master/package/mkpasswd/mkpasswd.c#L74-L75

```
static const char valid_salts[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789./";
```